# vuejs current timestamp moving

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have current timestamp function which return date and time but it does not move (meaning: seconds and minutes etc. just show when the page is loaded and are not live)

**What I want:** I want the time moving and not to be static

#### Code

`script`

```
methods: {
  currentDateTime() {
      const current = new Date();
      const date =
        current.getFullYear() +
        "-" +
        (current.getMonth() + 1) +
        "-" +
        current.getDate();
      const time =
        current.getHours() +
        ":" +
        current.getMinutes() +
        ":" +
        current.getSeconds();
      const dateTime = date + " " + time;

      return dateTime;
    },
}
```

`HTML`

```
{{ currentDateTime() }}
```

`screenshot`

[image: one]

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentDateTime()` will be executed only once. Use `setInterval()` to execute every 1 second.

```
data: {
    timestamp: ''
},
mounted: function () {
    setInterval(() => { this.currentDateTime() }, 1000)
  }
}),
methods: {
  currentDateTime() {
      const current = new Date();
      const date =
        current.getFullYear() +
        "-" +
        (current.getMonth() + 1) +
        "-" +
        current.getDate();
      const time =
        current.getHours() +
        ":" +
        current.getMinutes() +
        ":" +
        current.getSeconds();
      const dateTime = date + " " + time;
      this.timestamp = dateTime;
    },
}
```

`HTML`

```
{{ timestamp }}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `clearInterval` in `beforeDestroy`.